# What does the disableWakeEvent parameter of the SetSuspendState function do?

Tags: c#, .net

I am unable to understand what the disableWakeEvent parameter of the SetSuspendState function does.

The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate.aspx) explains it as "true to disable restoring the system's power status to active on a wake event, false to enable restoring the system's power status to active on a wake event."

So my question is, if I set it as true, and try to switch on my system after hibernate/suspend, will my system wake up or not?

```
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's explained a bit better in the equivalent [native API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201.aspx).

> **DisableWakeEvent**
>
> If this parameter is TRUE, the system disables
>   all wake events. If the parameter is FALSE, any system wake events
>   remain enabled.

Wake events are things like scheduled tasks that can wake the machine. For example, perhaps you have a scheduled task to wake the machine up to perform a full virus scan once a week.

Setting `disableWakeEvent` to `true` will disable all those other wake events. So when the system suspends, it stays suspended even if any such wake events are defined.